# How to make my button unclickable/invisible on press at the start of an eventListener function (not at the end)?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a button that when pressed, conducts a function. The function takes a few seconds to run. Whilst it is running I don't want to be able to press it again.

I have tried to remove the button and replace it at the end and I have tried to disable the button and replace it at the end. However, for both the button is only disabled/disappeared once it has finished its function(despite this being one of the early functions).

Any suggestions?

```
document.querySelector(DOM.domString.refreshButtonDom).addEventListener("click",function(event){
 console.log(event);
  event.preventDefault(); 
  document.querySelector(DOM.domString.refreshButtonDom).disabled = true;
  //UIControl.removeRefresh();
  UIControl.removeButtons();
  UIControl.bookieCheck();

  let ctryDOM = document.getElementById(DOM.domString.ctryDDDOM);
  let mktDOM = document.getElementById(DOM.domString.mktDDDOM);
  let sortDOM = document.getElementById(DOM.domString.sortDDDOM);
  let country_field=ctryDOM.options[ctryDOM.selectedIndex].value;
  let sort_field = sortDOM.options[sortDOM.selectedIndex].value;
  let mkt_field = mktDOM.options[mktDOM.selectedIndex].value;

  let allCalculations = new Array();



JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sportsData")).data.data.forEach(x=>{ 

  let currentSport = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(x.key)).data.data; 

  let clensedSport = api.clenseData(currentSport);


  if (clensedSport)
  {


    let calculations =arbitrage.calculateAll(clensedSport);

allCalculations=[...allCalculations,...calculations];


  }

  })

  if (refreshData === true){
    api.getSportsList();}
    else{
  if (sort_field == "date"){
  allCalculations.sort(function(a,b){return b[13]-a[13]});}
  else {  allCalculations.sort(function(a,b){return b[3]-a[3]});}


if (allCalculations.length < 1)
{console.log("No arbitrage was found - try enabling more bookmakers");}

  allCalculations.forEach(y=>{
    if(y[3]>0){
      //console.log(y);
    UIControl.addButtons(y[12],`${y[10]} v ${y[11]}`, y[13], y[3]);}
 });}

 document.querySelector(DOM.domString.refreshButtonDom).disabled = false;
//UIControl.addRefresh();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

### ***You can use a flag.***

so the initial value of flag is false and
when your function is running you can set the flag to "true" which means your not eligible to run the function at this time. and when the function is done it's sets back the flag to false

Here is a sample

---

```
flag = false;

function runOnclick() {

  if (flag == false) {
    flag = true;
    // run the logic of function

    // when function is done it set back the flag to false. which means we done it
    flag = false;
  }

 }
```

Comment: I'm getting some bizarre results with this. This seems to just queue the button clicks.  Each gets pressed after the entire function has run :(

Comment: at the first line of function it decide to run other part of your function or not. and I it just take some nanoseconds to do such decide and it's not such a big deal

Comment: When I press my button, it takes 3-5 seconds to run. I have implemented your solution and If I press it 5 times successively it takes 15-25 seconds to run because it is running the result back to back 5 times. Rather than checking the flag statement, it just waits until the last click has finished. Hence it will always pass the flag.

Comment: wrap all of your logic (that take 3-5 second) to an if clause. and the clause only run if it have permission. and I don't think it take more than 1 nanosecond to check a flag and execute the process.

Comment: just wrap all the logic to if clause. and if a user click a button million of times with no delay it doesn't matter